# How to keep my livewire component from refreshing while changing select

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Longtime Laravel user just started on livewire and wireui. Think I am missing something fundamental. Not sure if this is a wireui issue or livewire one

I have a form with 2 fields and a submit button additionally I have a description field that is set based upon the selection from the first select. Eventually my component will be a stepped form but I have to get past step one first.

My issue is if I remove the "wire.model.defer" my component does not update with the description field if I leave the defer my component refreshes when I make a change to the select but it doesn't happen all the time.

I have noticed if I hit the browser back button then forward again I am not seeing the refresh behavior.
Could this be related to tailwind JIT? How can I trouble shoot this?

**Component**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\ActionType;
use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Action;
use auth;

class NewActionWizard extends Component
{
    public 
    $selectedVehicle = null,
    $selectedAction = null, 
    $successMessage = '', 
    $currentStep = 1,
    $actionTypes=null, 
    $action=null, 
    $vehicles=null,
    $user=null;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->getActionTypes();
        $this->user = auth()->user();
        $this->vehicles = $this->user->vehicles;
    }

    /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.new-action-wizard');
    }

    public function updatedSelectedAction($action_type_id)
    {
        $this->action = ActionType::where('id', $action_type_id)->first();
    }

    public function getActionTypes ()
    {
        $this->actionTypes = ActionType::select('id', 'name')->get();
    }

    /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function firstStepSubmit()
    {
        $validatedData = $this->validate([
            'selectedAction'  => 'required|integer',
            'selectedVehicle' => 'required|integer',
        ]);

        $this->currentStep++;
    }

    /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function secondStepSubmit()
    {
       $this->currentStep++;
    }
    /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function thirdStepSubmit()
    {
        $this->currentStep++;
    }   

    /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function submitForm()
    {
        //do something

        $this->successMessage = 'Product Created Successfully.';

        $this->clearForm();

        $this->currentStep = 1;
    }

    /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function back($step)
    {
        $this->currentStep = $step;
    }

    /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function clearForm()
    {
        $this->name = '';
        $this->amount = '';
        $this->status = 1;
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@props([
    'active_css' => "text-teal-600 dark:text-teal-500 "
])
<div>

    @if(!empty($successMessage))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ $successMessage }}
    </div>
    @endif

    <ol class="flex items-center w-full text-sm font-medium text-center text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 sm:text-base">
        <li
            class="flex md:w-full items-center text-teal-600 dark:text-teal-500 sm:after:content-[''] after:w-full after:h-1 after:border-b after:border-gray-200 after:border-1 after:hidden sm:after:inline-block after:mx-6 xl:after:mx-10 dark:after:border-gray-700">
            <span wire:click="back(1)" class="flex items-center after:content-['/'] sm:after:hidden after:mx-2 after:text-gray-200 dark:after:text-gray-500">
                <x-ct-icon name="check-circle" class="w-5 h-5 mr-2 sm:w-6 sm:h-6" solid />
                <span>Action Type</span>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li
            class="{{ $currentStep >1 ? $active_css :'' }} flex md:w-full items-center after:content-[''] after:w-full after:h-1 after:border-b after:border-gray-200 after:border-1 after:hidden sm:after:inline-block after:mx-6 xl:after:mx-10 dark:after:border-gray-700">
            <span wire:click="back(2)" class="flex items-center after:content-['/'] sm:after:hidden after:mx-2 after:text-gray-200 dark:after:text-gray-500">
                @if($currentStep >1)
                    <x-ct-icon name="check-circle" class="w-5 h-5 mr-2 sm:w-6 sm:h-6" solid/>
                @else
                    <span class="mr-2">2</span>
                @endif
                <span>Profile</span><span class="hidden sm:inline-flex sm:ml-2">Info</span>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li
            class="{{ $currentStep >2 ? $active_css :'' }} flex md:w-full items-center after:content-[''] after:w-full after:h-1 after:border-b after:border-gray-200 after:border-1 after:hidden sm:after:inline-block after:mx-6 xl:after:mx-10 dark:after:border-gray-700">
            <span wire:click="back(3)" class="flex items-center after:content-['/'] sm:after:hidden after:mx-2 after:text-gray-200 dark:after:text-gray-500">
                @if($currentStep >2)
                    <x-ct-icon name="check-circle" class="w-5 h-5 mr-2 sm:w-6 sm:h-6" solid />
                @else
                    <span class="mr-2">3</span>
                @endif
                <span>Vehicle</span> <span class="hidden sm:inline-flex sm:ml-2">Info</span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </li>

        <li class="{{ $currentStep >3 ? $active_css :'' }}flex items-center">
            Confirmation
        </li>
    </ol>

    @if ($currentStep ===1)
    <div class="max-w-xl mx-auto my-4 space-y-6 sm:px-6 lg:px-8" >
        <div class="p-4 space-y-4 bg-white shadow sm:p-8 dark:bg-gray-800 sm:rounded-lg">
                <h3>Please select reason for your CARBTest service Request</h3>

                <div>
                    <x-ct-select 
                        wire:model="selectedAction"
                        placeholder="CARBTest Action Type" 
                        :options="$actionTypes"
                        option-label="name" 
                        option-value="id" 
                    />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <x-ct-select 
                        wire:model="selectedVehicle" 
                        placeholder="Select vehicle &hellip;" 
                    >
                        <x-ct-select.option label="Add New Vehicle" value="new" />
                        @foreach($vehicles as $vehicle)
                        <x-ct-select.option label="{{ $vehicle->vin }}" value="{{ $vehicle->id }}" />
                            
                        @endforeach
                    </x-ct-select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    @if(isset($selectedAction) && $action->id == 1)
                    <x-ct-input label="nst" placeholder="your name" hint="Notice to Submit to Testing (NST) Tracking Number"/>
                    @endif
                </div>


                <div > 
                @if($action)
                <p>{{ $action->description }}</p>
                @endif
                </div>
                <div class="flex justify-end">
                    <x-ct-button teal label="Next" wire:click="firstStepSubmit" class=""/>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endif
    
    @if ($currentStep ===2)
        <h3 class="text-xl">Update Profile Information</h3>
        @include('profile.partials.update-profile-information-form')
        <div class="flex justify-end space-x-4">
            <x-ct-button wire:click="back({{ $currentStep-1  }})">Back</x-ct-button>
            <x-ct-button teal label="Next" wire:click="secondStepSubmit" class=""/>
        </div>
    @endif
        
    @if ($currentStep ===3)
        <p>Step {{ $currentStep }}</p>
        <div class="flex justify-end space-x-4">
            <x-ct-button wire:click="back({{ $currentStep-1 }})">Back</x-ct-button>
            <x-ct-button teal label="Submit" wire:click="submitForm"/>
        </div>    
    @endif
</div>
```

Comment: browser back button then forward can't do anything 
may be use <div wire:poll.visible></div> or use alpinejs

Comment: As the [docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#deferred-updating) describe, `defer` is used when you don't want live updates. When a property is deferred, it will only be sent to the backend with the next request. If you want live updates, why add the `defer` prop? Just use `wire:model` or `wire:model.lazy`. As for browser back and forth, browsers try and cache the page as good as possible. You can't really cache Livewire since it updates actively. So, instead you might want to ask users to not do that using `onbeforeunload`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: I can confirm the random refresh issue was indeed related to JIT editing when I was running `npm run dev` when I cancelled that or ran `npm run build` I was not experiencing the issue.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior. New to Laravel & Livewire (have done some Vue dev work in the past... Might give Splade a try (especially the v2.0 version looks rather interesting, once it is released).